# is it possible to move points along curve normals (Geometry Nodes)

Tags: normals

I'm currently trying to setup a looping animation using geometry nodes where I can array objects along a curve endlessly, I've managed to get it to work fine with just a single instance but once I want to add more along the curve using a curve to points node I'm no longer able to move these instances along the normals of the curve?

So far I can only think to use the Vector math node to control the offset but that seems to move them along the incorrect normals as you can see in the 2nd image... any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

with this node setup:

[image]

you can control speed and distance:

[image]

Comment: Amazing! thank you so much that's exactly what I was looking for :)) 
Would there be an easy way to orient all the cubes in line with the normals of the curve as well? so they rotate with the curve as they're moving along it.. hope that makes sense